# Two-items footer centered with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer

I'm trying to create a footer with 2 elements (logo and copyright) using flexbox.
This is the code:

```css
footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 45px;
}

footer div {
    flex: 1;
}

footer img {
    width: 5%;
    height: auto;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Copyright Hair Day Salon 2022</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I want to center each element on its side of the flex, but justify-content doesn't work.
I also tried to remove flex: 1 from the article and do it afterward, but then the text will wrap into 2 lines and the logo will get bigger (things that I don't want).

What do you think is the issue and how could I center the div elements on the footer?
Thanks.

Comment: _I want to center each element on its side of the flex_ <- Does it mean logo is center on left column and copyright is center on right column? Would be good if you provide sample image of what it suppose to be.

Comment: Hi! Yes, you are right. The logo centered on the left and the copyright centered on the right. Unfortunately, I don't have a sample of what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some styling and resolved the issue using text-align:

```html
<footer>
    <div class="left">
        <img src="./img/logo2.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Copyright Hair Day Salon 2022</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

```css
footer {
    border: 1px #CF5F4B solid;
    margin: 45px auto;
}

footer img {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

footer .left {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

footer .right {
    width: 49%;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `justify-content: center`. just remove your

```
footer div {
 flex: 1
}
```

to adjust your image

```css
footer {
    display: flex;
    margin: 45px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

footer div {

}

footer .image-inside {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

footer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="image-inside">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Copyright Hair Day Salon 2022</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```